# Zip files that match certain data pattern within the file

Tags: grep, zip

I have a directory full of files `*.CLM_01`. I want to create 1 zip file with all files which have the value "005010X222" inside the file. Basically, there are a few files that have "005010X223" which I want to exclude from the zip. They are mutually exclusive. These values are in the data of the file not the file name.

I tried this but it' still zipping all files into 1 zip file

```
for f in *.CLM_01; do zip -ur test.zip $f | grep "005010X222" $f ; done
```

Comment: Each file should be archived into separate `.zip` file or all files should go into one `.zip` file?

Comment: all files should go into one .zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` with a quiet `grep` test:

```
find -name '*CLM_01' -exec grep -q '005010X222' {} \; -print0 | xargs -0 zip -u all_files.zip +
```

`-q` in `grep` is the quiet option, that only succeeds (exit code 0) on a match.

Best is to also use `-u` in `zip` in case `xargs` needs to call `zip` multiple times.

Comment: I tried this but received the error below



find: missing argument to `-exec'
        zip warning: all_files.zip not found or empty
        zip warning: name not matched: +

Comment: @Hedi my bad - code corrected

Comment: Thank you! That worked

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` and GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
zip file.zip ${(0)"$(grep -l --null 005010X222 ./*.CLM_01)"}
```

If your `grep` doesn't take a `--null` but you can guarantee none of the file names contain newline characters:

```
zip file.zip ${(f)"$(grep -l 005010X222 ./*.CLM_01)"}
```

With other POSIX-like shells, you could do the same with the split+glob operator:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline
set -o noglob # disable glob
zip file.zip $(grep -l 005010X222 ./*.CLM_01)
```

If you have `bsdtar`, you can also pass the list of files null-delimited on its stdin with `--null -T -`:

```
grep -l --null 005010X222 ./*.CLM_01 | bsdtar --null -T - -acf file.zip
```

The GNU implementation of `grep` can also look for the `*.CLM_01` files recursively by itself with:

```
grep --include='*.CLM_01' -rl --null 005010X222 . |
  bsdtar --null -T - -acf file.zip
```

That one isn't affected by the limit on the number of arguments that is passed to a command since the file paths are not passed as arguments to `grep` or `bsdtar`, but note that contrary to the glob-based solutions above, it will also consider hidden files.

With GNU `grep`, see also `grep -L 005010X223` to list the files that do *not* contain 005010X223 instead of `grep -l 005010X222` to list the ones that do contain 005010X222.

Comment: Is one limited by `ARG_MAX` / `ulimit` here?

Comment: @FelixJN, yes, except for the last one using `grep -r | bsdtar`